# Defining pointers vs accessing values in an Array in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, pointers

Let's say I'm passing the following array to a method:

```
input = [1,9,10,3,2,3,11,0,99,30,40,50]
```

I need to work with sets of 4 numbers from that array as follows:

```
OPCODE = input[0] # first of the 4 numbers
pos1_pointer = will always be opcode position + 1 position to the right
pos2_pointer = will always be opcode position + 2 positions to the right
output = will always be opcode position + 3 positions to the right
```

pos1 and pos2 numbers are actually pointers to the actual values (eg. pos1_pointer = 9 (one position from opcode), actual value 30 (position 9 in the array).

How do I define the pointer based on where the OPCODE is sitting?

I've tried:

```
pos1_pointer = input[input[opcode] + 1] # points to 40 which is wrong (because opcode = input[0] which is 1, and it sums 9 positions to that, position 10 being value 40)
pos1_pointer = input[opcode + 1] # is also wrong because it assigns a value of 2 to it (it sums 1 to the value of opcode which is 1)
```

Comment: Don't use `OPCODE` as a variable name. Ruby will think you're defining a constant, which may lead to warnings or other surprises in your code execution. Use `opcode` instead.

Answer (score 0):

### Use Iterators Rather Than Indexing

In Ruby, if you want to work with subsets of an array, there's a method for that! [Array#each_slice](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice) can be used to feed your slices directly into a method, or to deconstruct them further. For example:

```
input = [1, 9, 10, 3, 2, 3, 11, 0, 99, 30, 40, 50]

input.each_slice(4) do |slice|
  opcode, pos1, pos2, output = slice
  pp slice
end
```

You could replace `pp slice` with a call to your method(s) of choice, passing in either the whole slice or the deconstructed values as positional or keyword arguments. Let Ruby manage the indexing so you can focus on more important things.

Answer (score 0):

Why not try this. The first argument, `arr`, is the array. The second argument, `i`, is the index at which you want to start from.

The method bellow will take the array and the index and then return an array starting from the whichever index, in this case `0`, and then return everything between index `0` and index `0+3`.

Double dots `x..y` means go from range `x` up to `y`. Triple dot `x...y` means start from `x` and go up to BUT exclude `y`.

```
def four(arr, i)
  return arr[i..i+3]
end

print four([1,9,10,3,2,3,11,0,99,30,40,50],0) 
# input = [1,9,10,3,2,3,11,0,99,30,40,50]
# output = [1,9,10,3]
```